# What to do when you added a bounty but the most voted answer is not an answer actually?

Tags: support, bounties

I've asked a question on AI, and because it don't got much attention I created a bounty. With this I got some answers. They do add extra research and info, which is good, but do not resolve my problem.

The bounty is going to end and as I don't got any good reply I don't want it to be awarded, but there's an answer with 2 upvotes. What can I do?

[This is the question I'm talking about.](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/4822/trying-to-make-snake-learn-different-directions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [help center](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount

The answer you're talking about was created after the bounty and has a score of 2. You can't downvote it (you need 125 reputation for that), so it is eligible to be awarded automatically. You could award the bounty to the other answer, but other than that, there's nothing you can do about it. Even writing a self answer (and getting three upvotes) wouldn't help; you cannot award bounties to your own answers.

Comment: Yep, that's why I'm worried about the 2 upvotes it has. So I have to admit that I'm going to lose the rep and also not get any more visibility to receive a good answer... damn. EDIT: Nice glasses you have xD

Comment: You do not lose any more reputation. You've already 'paid' when the bounty started.

Comment: Oh, I thought that if noone is elegible to get the bounty, it returns to me. By the way, if I want more visibility again, I will have to "pay" again :-/

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález That’s right. Once you buy the bounty, you’ve spent the rep and it’s not refundable. Think of it like buying an advertisement. You’re paying money in the hopes you’ll get more “customers”, but what you’re actually buying is an ad, and if it’s not effective, it’s not effective. The money is still gone. And you have to pay again if you want to run another ad. No guarantees in life :/

Comment: @DanBron Ok, got it. Makes sense to me. Thank you for the example.